# How can I go about integrating FOSUser Registration & Login into another form in Symfony 2.1?

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

Reading around and playing with what I've got, I've concluded that I'm on the right path simply embedding the form(s) like any other:

```
$builder->add('user', 'fos_user_registration', array(
    'label' => 'Sign up',
    'error_bubbling' => false
));
```

And I've been theorising that I'd have to align my validation groups with those of FOSUser?:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'ACME\ReviewBundle\Entity\Review',
        'flowStep' => 1,
        'validation_groups' => array('Registration', 'Profile')
    ));
}
```

Perhaps with `Default` too?:

```
        'validation_groups' => array('Default', 'Registration', 'Profile')
```

---

However, the validation is still passing and it falls over at database level, so I'm guessing I need to do something else to assign the validation groups?

---

Beyond that, I'm also unsure how the processing of this is going to work, I could rip a load of it out of the FOSUser form handler and controller, but this seems a bit wet, and I'm wondering whether there is a better way? It would be nice to have it all reliant on the same logic.

To give some context, I'm using CraueFormFlow and I have a process a user needs to be able to start either authed or not. If they are unauthed, the a later step in the process needs them to either register or login.

I need to retain the data collected prior to authentication, which as far as I see, if I can embed the registration and login forms within my main form, should happen naturally.

Note: I have email confirmation off, so that isn't a concern, and it should be possible to make the entire process linear, with the user coming out authenticated and having had their review submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed an `@Assert` annotation, otherwise the validation isn't applied.